# How to insert text inside the rhombus of Milestone

Tags: pgfgantt

I am trying to write some text inside the Milestone symbol:
as stated in here [(P25)](https://tools.ietf.org/doc/texlive-doc/latex/pgfgantt/pgfgantt.pdf)

```
\begin{ganttchart}[vgrid, hgrid]{10}
\gantttitle{Title}{10} \\
\ganttbar{Task 1}{1}{5} \\
\ganttmilestone%
[milestone label font=\color{magenta}\rotatebox{30},
milestone label text={#1 !!!}]{Milestone}{5}
\ganttmilestone[inline]{2nd}{7}
\ganttmilestone%
[inline, milestone label inline anchor/.style=below]{3rd}{9}
\end{ganttchart}
```

it is possible to write using `inline`. However, this does not seem to work.
Any help on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I corrected some of your code (like the `%` signs after `\ganttmilestone`)

[image: z]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\begin{document}

    \begin{ganttchart}[vgrid,%
        hgrid,
        x unit=1.0cm,
        y unit title=1.5cm,
        y unit chart=1.0cm,
        milestone label font=\tiny\itshape,
        group label font=\tiny\bfseries,
        bar label font=\scriptsize,
        milestone/.append style={fill=orange!60},
        milestone inline label node/.append style={left=-3mm},  % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        milestone height= 0.8, 
        milestone label font=\tiny\itshape,
        ]{1}{7}
        \gantttitle{ Timeline}{7} \\
        \ganttgroup{Duration}{1}{7} \\
        \ganttbar{Reading}{1}{2} \\
        \ganttbar{Review}{2}{3} \\
        \ganttbar{Define Scope}{5}{6} \\
        \ganttbar{Relevant}{4}{6} \\\
        \ganttbar{Classify}{6}{7}\\
        \ganttmilestone[milestone label font=\color{magenta}\scriptsize\itshape,
                        milestone label node/.append style={rotate=30},
                        milestone label text={#1 !!!}]{Milestone 1}{2}\\
        \ganttmilestone[inline]{2nd}{3}\\
        \ganttmilestone[inline]{3rd}{5}\\
        \ganttbar{The End}{7}{7}

    \end{ganttchart}

\end{document}
```